# Phusion Passenger file not found when the file exits

Tags: node.js, apache, passenger, cpanel

I am getting the following error even though I have verified that the PassengerAgent exists at that location. The application I am trying to run is a nodeJS application on a cPanel apache server. I have root access to the server.

```
An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:

SpawnPreparerShell: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.28/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out what my problem was. I had CageFS installed and activated. Even though the permissions and ownership to PassengerAgent were correct, somehow CageFS was still blocking access to it from the user. I still need to figure out how to prevent CageFS from blocking it, but at least I know what the problem is. I will probably change the installation to a new directory. I will post another reply when I have discovered how to let CageFS and Phusion Passenger work together.